# Why do I receive spam after setting postfix to redirect incoming mails to other user based on receiver address?

Tags: email, postfix-mta, spam-prevention

So far my `main.cf` contained, primarily, two following lines:

```
local_recipient_maps =
luser_relay = mrjoe@mydomain.com
```

These settings are responsible for delivering all emails sent to any address in my domain like `random_string@mydomain.com` to my real account `mrjoe@mydomain.com`. This worked and I was receiving emails only from websites where I signed up with any of my unlimited aliases.

I realized that I don't want to receive all these emails, so I came up with an idea to discard emails sent to particular alias instead of blocking a particular sender. In this way, I can protect myself from any future unwanted email and somehow make this alias disabled.

To bring this idea to life I removed the previous two lines from `main.cf` and added the following one:

```
virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias
```

The `virtual_alias` file has following content:

```
/^((?!^(blacklisted_address|another_blacklisted)@).)*$/ mrjoe@mydomain.com
```

This configuration redirects all emails sent to addresses other than `blacklisted_address@mydomain.com` and `another_blclisted@mydomain.com` to specified real address `mrjoe@mydomain.com`.

This works, emails sent to listed addresses are not delivered to my inbox. The problem is that now I started to receive hundreds of spam emails, **none of which I received before**.

Here is one example of such spam message:

> From secretariat@solid-app-api.be  Wed May 29 01:23:10 2019
>   Return-Path: <secretariat@solid-app-api.be>
>   X-Original-To: mrsnorah11@gmail.com
>   Delivered-To: mrjoe@mydomain.com
>   Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
>   Content-Description: Mail message body
>   Subject: 21.21.21.21 // my IP here
>   To: Recipients <secretariat@solid-app-api.be>
>   From: "Agent MacLeod" <secretariat@solid-app-api.be>
>   Date: Tue, 28 May 2019 16:23:10 -0700
>   X-UID: 1194
>   Content-Length: 3686
>   Status: RO

So the question is: **why did I start to receive hundreds of spam messages after making changes described above? How is it possible that now messages with** `X-Original-To` **header different than** `@mydomain.com` **are delivered to my domain?**

As for now, I brought back the previous configuration and I no longer receive spam messages. Clearly, this is not an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your old config, `luser_relay` delivered all ["mail for unknown recipients in domains that match $mydestination, $inet_interfaces or $proxy_interfaces"](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#luser_relay) (thus your domain) to your mailbox.

Your new configuration accepts mails for *any* recipient domain. The regex matches *any* email address except the blacklisted ones. All mails forwarded to your address `mrjoe@mydomain.com`, hence the `X-Original-To` header.

Spammers send mails with other repients (like gmail.com) to your server because your server accepts it. They think that you're running an [open relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay) (which you probably don't).